# MySql Crashed When Starting Xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, crash, xampp

When I started the MYSQL from Xampp it crashed. It gave me this error:

```
8:32:33 AM [mysql] Attempting to start MySQL app... 
8:32:33 AM [mysql] Status change detected: running 
8:32:37 AM [mysql] Status change detected: stopped 
8:32:37 AM [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 
8:32:37 AM [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 8:32:37 AM [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 8:32:37 AM [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 
8:32:37 AM [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 8:32:37 AM [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this 
8:32:37 AM [mysql] entire log window on the forums

error log InnoDB: using atomic writes.  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active. 
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 73242724; transaction id 45388 
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.  
2020-05-13 8:26:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Can someone please help me and tell what actually is happening

Comment: How is PHP related? Have your tried the issues noted in the log?

Comment: Hey have you got the answer yet!

Comment: i uninstalled and reinstalled it then works like a charm@Uncias

Answer (score 2):

Probably your port is busy. If you use Linux you can try to run "lsof -i" to detect what is using your port.

Comment: i am using windows 10

Comment: You can try to change mysql port number on xampp or type to cmd
netstat -aon | findstr '[port_number]'

Answer (score 0):

Well I also used to get this kind of problem. I resolved this error like this:

1) Open the Xampp control panel and click Services[image]

2)Find the MYSQL08 option. It might show the service is started.

[image]

3)Stop  the service and try starting the mysql again

[image: You can even restart the service]

Hope so it might help you.